# Haskell Processing text from a file

Tags: string, haskell, text-processing

**Hi Guys,**

### 1. What do I want to do?

I get a 1-lined file with text

```
"Bangabang [Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing] [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]"
```

I want to read this text from a file and convert it to:

```
[[Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing], [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing], [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing], [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]]
```

Which is a `[[Maybe Integer]]` type.

### 2. What have I already done?

I can modify normal `String` to `Maybe Integer`

My String:

```
xxx = "Bangabang [Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing] [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]"
```

after executing **`stripChars ",]" $ drop 10 xxx`** I get:

```
"Just 31 Nothing Just 1 Nothing [Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing [Nothing Nothing Just 4 Nothing [Nothing Just 3 Nothing Nothing"
```

after next commands **`map (splitOn " ") $ splitOn "["`** I have:

```
[["Just","31","Nothing","Just","1","Nothing",""],["Nothing","Nothing","Nothing","Nothing",""],["Nothing","Nothing","Just","4","Nothing",""],["Nothing","Just","3","Nothing","Nothing"]]
```

Now I have to cut off that empty strings `""` using **`cleany`**
And finally change `[[String]]` to `[[Maybe Integer]]` using **`cuty`**

```
 [[Just 31,Nothing,Just 1,Nothing],[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing],[Nothing,Nothing,Just 4,Nothing],[Nothing,Just 3,Nothing,Nothing]]
```

**That is what I wanted to have!**

### 3. The problem is...

...how can I execute this method:

```
parse xxx = cuty $ cleany $ map (splitOn " ") $ splitOn "[" $ stripChars ",]" $ drop 10 xxx
```

on text read from file (which is IO String type)?

This is my first Haskell project, so my functions may reinvent the wheel or do worse things :/

### Used functions:

```
main do     
      text <- readFile "test.txt"
      let l = lines
      map parse . l



-- deletes unwanted characters from a String
stripChars :: String -> String -> String
stripChars = filter . flip notElem


-- converts String to Maybe a   
maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead s = case reads s of
    [(x,"")] -> Just x
    _ -> Nothing

-- convert(with subfunction conv, because I don't know how to make it one function)

conv:: [String] -> [Maybe Integer]
conv[] = []
conv(x:xs) =  if x == "Just" then conv xs
                else maybeRead x: conv xs

convert:: [[String]] -> [[Maybe Integer]]
convert[] = []
convert(x:xs) = conv x : convert xs

-- cleany (with subfunction clean, because I don't know how to make it one function)    

clean :: [String] -> [String]
clean [] = []
clean (x:xs) = if x == "" then clean xs
                else x : clean xs

cleany :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
cleany [] = []
cleany (x:xs) = clean x : cleany xs
```

Comment: Please don't split your code with non-code snippets. This will only make copy&paste awkward.

Comment: @Zeta just edited. Thanks for an advice!

Comment: Define `data Bangabang = ... deriving Read` and simply `read` to parse your file.

Comment: @josejuan thanks. going to read about deriving mechanism and how to use it!

Comment: @josejuan - deriving Read doesn't quite work - it doesn't handle a variable number of sublists.

Comment: Are not fixed (4 lists)?, then, split on `] [` and read again :)

Comment: @josejuan yeah, there always will be 4 lists

Comment: "How can I execute this on text read from a file (which is of `IO String` type)?" - text read from a file is a `String`, not an `IO String`. *The action of reading text from a file* could be an `IO String`, but the text itself is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're ok with a parser that does zero to minimal error checking. Haskell has great libraries for parsing, and later I'll amend my answer with some alternatives you should look at.

Instead of using `splitOn` I would recommend writing these functions:

```
takeList :: String -> (String, String)
-- returns the match text and the text following the match
-- e.g. takeList " [1,2,3] ..."  returns ("[1,2,3]", " ...")

takeLists :: String -> [String]
-- parses a sequence of lists separated by spaces
-- into a list of matches
```

I'll leave `takeList` as an exercise. I like to use `span` and `break` from Data.List for these kinds of simple parsers.

In terms of `takeList`, here is how you might write `takeLists`:

```
takeLists :: String -> [ String ]
takeLists str =
  let s1 = dropWhile (/= '[') str
  in if null s1
       then []
       else let (s2,s3) = takeList s1
            in   s2 : takeLists s3
```

For example, `takeLists " [123] [4,5,6] [7,8] "` will return:

```
[ "[123]", "[4,5,6]", "[7,8]" ]
```

Finally, to convert each string in this list to Haskell values, just use `read`.

```
answer :: [ [Int] ]
answer = map read (takeLists " [123] [4,5,6] [7,8] ")
```

**Update**

Using the ReadP and ReadS parsers available in the base libraries:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

bang :: ReadP [[Maybe Int]]
bang = do string "Bangabang"
          skipSpaces
          xs <- sepBy1 (readS_to_P reads) skipSpaces
          eof
          return xs

input = "Bangabang [Just 3, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing] [Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing] [Nothing, Just 3, Nothing, Nothing]"

runParser p input = case (readP_to_S p) input of
                      [] -> error "no parses"
                      ((a,_):_) -> print a

example = runParser bang input
```

Comment: thank you for your response!  I am not yet familiar with Haskell's Parsers :/  There is an assumption, that file will always be like "Bangabanga<spacebar>[Just Integer / Nothing]<spacebar>[Just Integer / Nothing]<spacebar>[Just Integer / Nothing]<spacebar>[Just Integer / Nothing]"

Comment: thanks for update. It works really great. Unfortunately the `:type example == IO()` and it has to be `[[Maybe Integer]]`, as it will be later used with another function ;(

Comment: Just change `print a` to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly `Read` instance.

```
data Bangabang = Bangabang [Maybe Integer]
                           [Maybe Integer]
                           [Maybe Integer]
                           [Maybe Integer] deriving (Read, Show)
```

now, you can use all `Read` machinery (`read`, `reads`, `readIO`, ...), inferred from types. E.g.

```
readBangabang :: String -> Bangabang
readBangabang = read
```

If data came from file

```
readFile "foo.txt" >>= print . readBangabang
```